# Использование промисов в конкретных реальных задачах

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, promise

В каких **конкретных реальных задачах** используются промисы? Какие есть **примеры практического использования** в реальных задачах (кроме динамической загрузки скриптов)? Приведите примеры, упорядоченные по **темам использования**. **Напишите, кто на практике использовал их**.

Comment: Если считать async/await за промисы - то везде)

Comment: Вообще слишком обширный вопрос. Применяются там где нужны. Вот и весь ответ..... например подождать settimeout очень пригождается или подождать bootbox.confirm вообще замечательно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский перечислите как можно больше примеров.

Comment: Ну что это за экзамен?)) Когда нужно - тогда и применяется.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский просто я недавно только изучил промисы по learn.javascript.ru - но не хватает практики. Не надо меня минусовать.

Comment: Это не моё (тем более два)........а в книгах как правило описаны моменты часто употребимые с элементом изучения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, необходимо обратиться к REST-сервису при помощи [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) (это более удобная замена XMLHttpRequest с хорошей поддержкой современными браузерами).

Функция `fetch` возвращает Promise, типичное использование которого выглядит так:

```js
fetch('https://api.my-server.ru')
  .then(response => response.json()) // парсим JSON
  .then(data => console.log(data))   // обрабатываем результат
```

Более сложные примеры использования `fetch` можно найти в [этом туториале](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Но из этого простого примера не ясно, в чем преимущество Promise пред обычными callback-запросами. А оно заключается в том, что с результатом Promise можно выполнять операции как с объектами.

Например, нам необходимо скачать три JSON-файла с разных эндпоинтов сервера и сделать операцию по окончании загрузки всех трех файлов. При помощи [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) это делается очень легко:

```js
const promiseNews = fetch('https://api.my-server.ru/news.json')
  .then(r => r.json());

const promisePosts = fetch('https://api.my-server.ru/posts.json')
  .then(r => r.json());

const promiseComments = fetch('https://api.my-server.ru/comments.json')
  .then(r => r.json());

Promise.all([promiseNews, promisePosts, promiseComments])
  .then(([news, posts, comments]) => {
    console.log('News:', news);
    console.log('Posts:', posts);
    console.log('Comments:', comments);
  })
```

Comment: а ввод данных в строку сообщений социальных сетей (посылка сообщений в мессенджере) можно организовать с помощью промисов? Ну чтобы отображалось в процессе ввода, что собеседник печатает ответ.

Comment: @vladwebmaster это скорее делается через https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API, у которого насколько я знаю нет нативной поддержки Promise. Но есть библиотеки вроде https://github.com/vitalets/websocket-as-promised, которые позволяют использовать WebSocket через Promise.